# Error with adding a variable that has repeated indices using Gurobi in Julia

Tags: julia, gurobi, julia-jump

I am using Gurobi with Julia to create a linear program, and I am having trouble adding a variable if it is indexed by a list with repeated elements.
Specifically, I am trying to do the following command:

```
@variable(model, materialResources[[1, 1]])
```

where model is the model I initialized in Gurobi by

```
model = Model(with_optimizer(Gurobi.Optimizer, OutputFlag=0));
```

The program spits back the following error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: Repeated index 1. Index sets must have unique elements.
```

How do I add an entry to my materialResources variable-vector if it is indexed by repeated elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add variables indexed by a set with repeated elements.

Otherwise, if you could, which variable would `materialResources[1]` refer to?

If you want a set with vectors as elements, use:

```
model = Model()
S = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
@variable(model, x[S])
x[[1, 1]]
```

Comment: But I am not adding materialResources[1] twice. I am adding an index [1, 1] which is a LIST. And that is a unique identifier in materialResources (or at least that is what I want it to be).

Comment: I updated the answer. Your syntax had the set `[1, 1]`. That's different from the set `[[1, 1]]` (that is, a vector where each element is a vector).